# Ticker merging numbers into one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two number tickers on my page and both tickers are merging into one.

**Demo:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var initialValue = $('#ticker .count').text()
  $('#ticker').waypoint({
    handler: function() {
      $('.count').each(function() {
        const format = formatter(initialValue)

        $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
          Counter: format.value
        }, {
          duration: 1500,
          easing: 'swing',
          step: function(now) {
            $(this).text(format.revert(Math.ceil(now)));
          }
        });
      });
    },
    offset: '100%'
  });
})

// keep string after count
function formatter(str) {
  const char = 'x'
  const template = str.replace(/\d/g, char)
  const value = str.replace(/\D/g, '')

  function revert(val) {
    const valStr = val.toString()
    let result = ''
    let index = 0
    for (let i = 0; i < template.length; i++) {
      const holder = template[i]
      if (holder === char) {
        result += valStr.slice(index, index + 1)
        index++
      } else {
        result += holder
      }
    }
    return result
  }
  return {
    template: template,
    value: value,
    revert: revert
  }
}
```

```css
.gap {
  background: lightgrey;
  height: 20px;
}

.gap2 {
  margin: 20px 0px;
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>

<div id="ticker">
  <span class="count counter">16,000+</span>
</div>

<div class="gap"></div>

<div id="ticker">
  <span class="count counter">$64 million</span>
</div>

<div class="gap2">Expected output below (but they obviously count up to that number)</div>

<!-- expected output -->

<div id="ticker">
  <span>16,000+</span>
</div>

<div class="gap"></div>

<div id="ticker">
  <span>$64 million</span>
</div>
```

Why is this happening? I believe the issue to be in this line:

```
const format = formatter(initialValue)
```

Because when commented out, although it doesn't count up, it only displays one number. But can't see why this is causing this merge?

Edit:

Have edited snippet to showcase expected end result.

Comment: what is the expected output

Comment: @NagaSaiA - See updated question :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're right. Please replace

```
const format = formatter(initialValue)
```

with

```
const format = formatter($(this).text());
```

This change will give you you're expected output.

You're traversing each "count" div so no need to store it in variable because that ".text()" line conbine output of all "count" div's.

So, fetch text of div in loop.